# Excel 2016 Assign computer names to IT teams

Tags: excel, formula

I have a list of a little over 1000 computer names, computer names are defined by country and city (e.g. computers names for New York office are USNYxxxx).
I have 14 countries and 8 IT teams.
I want to use a formula that will assign the computer names to the correct IT team per location.
For example Dave manages the IT office in New York so I'd like to have a formula that will search for all computer names USNYxxxx and put the name Dave in to a separate column.

Comment: This seems like a use of index() and match(), but without example data to see and work on, you can search on here for similar questions.

Comment: Looks like your initial char of every computer name will be always the same according to their city and location. For example, USNY0001, USNY0002, and so on. I think your best option would be to have a secondarr table where you can relate each group of computers to 1 team (in example, would be USNY related to Dave). Then just use a Vlookup  to fill your list. If any team changes in any moment, just change it in that secondary table.

Answer (score 0):

how about : `=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="USNY","Dave","")`

assuming A1 is the input field.